# How to pin FAB to bottom and make scroll possible while soft keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a layout with some TextInputLayouts (EditTexts) and a FAB which should stay pinned to bottom right. If I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, soft keyboard lifts up FAB, and if I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, the keyboard goes over FAB, but it doesn't scroll anymore. Is there a way to make both possible (i.e. keyboard goes over FAB and it scrolls properly)?

The layout goes like this:

```
RelativeLayout -> ScrollView -> RelativeLayout -> ...
               -> FAB
```

And the FAB code follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation" />
```

`android:isScrollContainer="false"` doesn't work.

Comment: It's not scrolling because all elements are still on the screen (even though they are hidden by the keyboard). As a work around, maybe you can hide the FAB whenever the keyboard is opened?

Comment: Right, makes sense, I guess that's the only solution then

Answer (score 0):

Put your FAB in CoordinatorLayout then set `layout_anchor` and `layout_anchorGravity` for FAB. It will help you

Answer (score 0):

`layout_anchor` and `layout_anchorGravity` used as shown below will anchor the FAB to the bottom of the page but still allow scrolling. This assumes `pageContainerViewGroup` the view we are anchoring to fills the screen.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/pageContainerViewGroup"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
```